# PostgreSQL: what are purpose of functions uuid_hash(uuid) and uuid_hash_extended(uuid, bigint)

Tags: postgresql, uuid, hashing

## Functions `uuid_hash` and `uuid_hash_extended`

Exploring postgresql I discovered 2 functions that looks interesting:

```sql
SELECT 
        p.proname ,
        obj_description(p.oid) AS func_desc,
        pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS args_def,
        string_to_array(pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid), ','::text) AS args,
        pg_get_function_result(p.oid) AS rettype 
    FROM 
        pg_catalog.pg_proc P        
    WHERE
        proname ~~ 'uuid_hash%'
```

| proname | func_desc | args_def | args | rettype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid_hash | hash | uuid | {uuid} | integer |
| uuid_hash_extended | hash | uuid, bigint | {uuid, bigint} | bigint |

Let's try to use them:

```sql
SELECT 
    uuid_hash(uuid_nil()),
    uuid_hash_extended(uuid_nil(), 0),
    uuid_hash(MD5('hello')::uuid),
    uuid_hash_extended(MD5('hello')::uuid, 0);
```

| uuid_hash | uuid_hash_extended | uuid_hash | uuid_hash_extended |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1353656403 | -6859010066814654381 | 1620818621 | -4122998508949357891 |

DB Feedle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8CG8HaFn6D2mLKLk3LTwx2/0

Hm.
Looks interesting and maybe has posssible uses.

Switching postgresql versions I noticed that `uuid_hash_extended` appeared in PostgreSQL 11.

Looking into postgresql documentation - I found nothing.

Web search - nothing too.

## Question

What is the purpose of those functions?

For what they could be used?

## UPDATE

A. The answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/295517/82983 is accepted. The source code of function looks very simple

B. Interesting usage found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66848699/1168212

Comment: From the names I guess(!) they are used for hash indexes and hash partitioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are used for `hash` index method. As clearly mentioned in [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/uuid.c#L403):

> hash index support

It's possible to track dependencies through pg_amproc/pg_opclass/pg_opfamily system catalogs, but this is not as obvious compared to the comment.

Since they are not documented for direct call by user, PostgreSQL developers community may decide to change/replace/remove such functions in new major release.